# OnSuccess Not being hit, cant get image download URL, fire base

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-storage

I have tried absolutely everything to try and get the Image URL after uploading and nothing seems to work. I have been on multiple Stack Overflow threads and still nothing... If someone can please see as to why i cannot get that would be amazing.

Thanks in advance

```
private void uploadFile(Bitmap bitmap) {
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://kidfinder-b082f.appspot.com");
    StorageReference mountainImagesRef = storageRef.child("kidfinder/" + getUserID() + ".jpg");
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 20, baos);
    byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
    UploadTask uploadTask = mountainImagesRef.putBytes(data);
    uploadTask.isSuccessful();
    uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            System.out.println("Image Upload Failed");
        }
    }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            System.out.println("Image Uploaded");
            @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests") Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
            setImageURL(downloadUrl.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

It is not hitting the OnSuccess method, not even the onFailed.

All of the links and childs are correct.

I have tried to add a `.isSuccessful()` at the end and still nothing.

I have done separate methods that require more or less the same thing and still nothing.

Gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Lastly, it is uploading the image perfectly.. Just not giving me the download image url.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

The other ways of getting the URL by just asking for it and assigning it to a string like so:

```
storageRef.child("CHILD STRING").getDownloadUrl().getResult();
```

Just gives me `no auth token for request firebase`

Did some research, and it is due to the rules of my storage space.. but it is completely public? like so:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found the resolution**

Just for anyone's curiosity, i figured it out.. i added this line at the bottom of the method and it worked.. It did so by working around to onSuccess methods.

```
@SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests")Uri downloadUrl = uploadTask.getSnapshot().getDownloadUrl();
    System.out.println(downloadUrl.toString());
```

I am guessing that it kind of forces the onSuccess rigger to execute